# Using Next.js 14 new Template feature, How can I pass data from children up to the template?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, callback

Goal: Have a subheader section in a template.js file containing a page title that updates when a new child is navigated to something like:

template.js

```
...
return(
<div>
  <div className="subheader">
    <h2>{data.title}</h2>
    <p>{data.description}</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
</div>)
```

child1.js

```
const Child1 = () => {

  const data = [
    {
      title: "Child 1"
    },
    {
      description: "Im the first child but my parent doesn't know that, why does it hate me?"
    }
  ];

  return (
      <div>
        Im a child component so dont blame me if I do childish things.
      </div>

  );
}
 
export default Child1;
```

To my knowledge as its a component and not a Page i can't use `getStaticProps` and I don't want to pass the data through the URL.  I've been playing with useState and useEffect but with no luck, so any ideas on how my parent template should get data from its children?

Comment: You cannot. This goes against React core logic. Only a parent can pass down data to it children, not the otherwise around.

Comment: yes, that's. I was under the impression that the Template feature was designed for this sort of use case, however upon further exploration, it seems it was not.  thanks

Comment: The better way: Always first describe **what(!)** you want to do (use case) and not **how** you intend to do! See my answer below. Please comment, if it is what you wish to do or explain your use case. Don't forget to mark your question as resolved, once you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Always first describe **what(!)** you want to do (use case) and not **how** you intend to do

---

This said, the React way to "pass data up" is `useState` and passing the state setter as a prop. If you can't pass props, use `useContext`.

```
// Pseudo code not tested
import { useState } from 'react';

function ParentComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState('Some initial state');
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data}</h1>
      <ChildComponent stateSetter={setData} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildComponent({ stateSetter }: { stateSetter: (data: string) => void }){
  return (
    <button onClick={() => stateSetter('I come from a child component.')}>
      Click me
    </button>
  );
}
```

But I don't think, it is what you really want. With App Router in Next 14 you can fetch data in React Server Components, React Client Components and passing around with smart caching strategies. Read more about these possibilities. Next.js offers helpful guidance and docs, including excellent tutorials. It's crucial to get this right for building successfully a Next.js 14 site.